# Dynamic ngModel (Dynamicly building a form in AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, forms, coffeescript

I am trying to build a form from a json data for a specific resource `Employee`

in my scope i have an `employee` and a `forms` property

the `forms` property have all the structured data of how the form is built, so when I create a field in the form, I want to link that form input with one of my resource attributes

here is my code on the controller (coffeescript)

```
app.controller 'SuperCtrl', ($scope) ->
  $scope.employee = {
    lastName: '',
    firstName:'',
  }

  $scope.forms = [
    id: "Personal Information"
    title: "Personal Information"
    sections: [
      rows: [
        fields: [
          {
            id: "first_name"
            key: "firstName"
            title: "First Name"
            type: "text"
            size: 33
            values: null
            validation: "[^()]"
          }
          {
            id: "last_name"
            key: "lastName"
            title: "Last Name"
            type: "text"
            size: 34
            values: null
            validation: "[^()]"
          }
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]

  return
```

and the part of the view that creates the form

```
<div ng-repeat="form in forms">
      <h1>title: {{ form.title }}</h1>

      <fieldset ng-repeat="section in form.sections">
        <h1>form</h1>
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="row in section.rows">
          <p ng-repeat="field in row.fields">
            <label for="{{ field.key }}">{{ field.title }}</label>
            {{ $log.log(field + " " + field.key) }}
            <input type="{{ field.type }}"
            name="{{ field.key }}"
            ng-model="employee[field.key]" />
          </p>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
```

I googled for dynamic ngmodel calls and I am doing the same thing as the answers `ng-model="employee[field.key]"` but for some reason I don't get the expected result

### Expected result

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="employee.firstName class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
```

### What I get

```
<input type="name" name="lastName" ng-model="employee[field.key]" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
```

I created a code pen with the full example http://codepen.io/fespinoza/pen/jsfAJ?editors=101

I hope you can help me

Comment: I've tried saying ng-model="employee[field][key]" and other combinations and either I get a syntax error or I get the same value I put on ng-model without being interpolated

Comment: I checked your code and it works for me, add {{employee}} somewhere in the code and see that its attributes are bound to inputs: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BylnC

Comment: I never thought of that... I was expecting all the time to generate that, that I never thought of the value of the scope

Comment: I will be grateful for upvoting my comment if it was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

as @cthulhu commented

my code works

the generated html was the one I expected, but the binding is correctly done, so the code worked all the time